# Batching field calculations and feature classes in feature dataset using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, cursor, iteration

I'm working on writing a script that will calculate facility ID's for feature classes in a feature dataset. Is there a way to do this without making feature layers and doing select/field calculate operations on all of them?

Basically, I'm wanting to iterate through the feature dataset and create a list of feature classes that can then have the field calc ran on each. The problem is that each feature class has a different expression for field calculation, and I need to select only null values, and the select layer by attribute function requires a feature layer.

Comment: It's not hard to make a feature layer from a feature class, read http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000 about MakeFeatureLayer. Your question is a little to vague to be helpful in any specific way; are you looking for a particular field that has Null values? Making a feature layer with a where clause '<field> is NULL'  coupled with int(arcpy.GetCount_management(YourFeatureLayer).getOutput(0)) will very quickly give you an idea of how many features have a null in their <field>.

Comment: Make an attempt using da.UpdateCursor and post a new question if you get stuck and include your code attempt.

Comment: I just need to calculate facility ID's for every feature class in a feature dataset, all using a common field. The problem is that each feature class has a different method if calculating the ID's. I'll try the update cursor. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the Field Calculator for this.  Instead I would use an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`:

> UpdateCursor establishes read-write access to records returned from a
>   feature class or table.
>
> Returns an iterator of lists. The order of values in the list matches
>   the order of fields specified by the field_names argument.

You will need to write various `if`/`elif`/`else` statements, use `ListFeatureClasses`, etc to complete your code.